# Large independent images floating in a divs background using CSS

Tags: css, image, bootstrap-4, background

Currently i am trying to add large PNG images on the background of a website (im also using Bootstrap 4). When a user resizes the screen the image will stay in place and so these independent images will stay a part of the background (except still being affected by CSS media queries)

An example of the kind of images i'm trying to put floating in the background:

[image: png phones no background]

An example of this effect can be scene on the Stripe payment website: [stripe.com](https://stripe.com)

- when resizing the page all the little graphics stay fixed on the page (even if being off-screened) and are affected by media queries.
- The globe also stays relatively fixed.

I know this seems to be a simple problem but everything ive tried has been in vain.

I am looking for preferably a simple structure like this:

*HTML*

```
<div id="media-section" class="container">
     <img  id="bCamera" src="{{ asset('imgs/bCamera.png') }}" width="500px" , height="500px"/>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#bCamera{
 position: relative;
 right: -70%;
}
```

The problem is that if the image is `position: absolute;`, then it will scale with the entire view width and not the inner container, but if it is `position: relative;` then it will be better position but it now affects the page flow.

**Therefore**: what is the best way to put a large independent image on the page floating on the background of a div without it affecting the flow of the page?

Answer (score 1):

`:after` is what you are looking for. You could try something like this.

```
<div id="media-section" class="container"></div>

#media-section:after {
 content: url('imgs/bCamera.png');
}
```

Comment: Honestly close. But when using the chrome Devtools debugger and resizing the view will break the page. i would prefer if the page is resizable by the chrome debugger without problem (if there is no other better answers posted then i will accept this answer in time) Edit: it seems that the page gets zoomed instead of having regular fluid responsiveness when resizing.

Comment: also wanted to add that the width and height does not affect the image size.